# Searching by check number after upgrading to 5.5.0

Tags: civicontribute

I recently upgraded to 5.5.0 and now when you edit a pending pay later contribution, add a check number, change status to complete and then i go to search contributions, enter the payment method and search by check number i get no result.

I

Answer (score 3):

I was able to replicate this issue.

Historically, CiviCRM didn't support multiple payments on a single contribution.  So the check number is part of the contribution.  However, now that it supports multiple payments, the check number is part of the financial transaction.

The check number being searched is the contribution's, not the financial transaction's.  I think it needs to be changed; I can't think of a case where it's desirable not to.

I just opened a ticket on https://lab.civicrm.org, [financial#37](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/37).

Comment: Do you have a suggestion that would solve this problem in the short term? I am sure there are others with this problem that maybe don't know it is an issue.

Comment: Afraid not, @WVMike.  It needs someone to look at it. Is your organization in a position to fund the fix?  As we like to say, CiviCRM is free to use, but not to write :)  If there was funding, I'm sure someone could get on it quite quickly, I don't think it's a ton of work to resolve.

Comment: Having same problem after the upgrade

Comment: @HassanFarooq I opened a ticket, but unless someone devotes resources to fixing it (code or money) it's probably going to remain that way.